# Make a live CD in a partition of my EHD?

Tags: boot, partitioning

I have about 2GB unallocated space in my 1TB EHD. I want to put a live CD image on it (and if possible, with persistence too). Is this possible?

I do this before on smaller flash drives using dd but that replaces the partition table of the whole drive (dd of=/dev/sdb ...) but I only want it on a partition so I have no idea right now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the process by myself and this is what I did:

I'm doing this in Linux and the process is simple. You need both [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

I made a Fat32 partition on my EHD using GParted with size enough for the distro image. I then used UNetbootin to make a live CD from it.